# Quickest/Shortest in C/C++ method to calculate sum of digits in binary/aka number of 1s in binary

Tags: c++, c, performance, binary, shortest

I have a liking to finding shortest methods for coding. I have found a need for a method for calculating the sum of the digits(or the number of 1s in a number) of a number represented in binary. I have used bit operators and found this:

```
r=1;while(a&=a-1)r++;
```

where a is the number, and r is the count. a is a given integer. Is there any way to shorten this/improve the algorithm?

Shortest as in shortest length of source code.

Comment: What is the type of `a`? There are faster ways, but I think it would be difficult to make this algorithm shorter.

Comment: There is a resp. section in the famous [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) (look for "Counting bits set").

Comment: a is an integer @Bathsheba

Comment: This kind of operation is commonly referred to as "hamming weight" or "population count". I think some processors have an instruction to do precisely this, and I wouldn't be surprised if some compilers provided intrisics for this as well. It might be helpful if you desperately want speed to the point of giving up portability.

Comment: @Caninonos I need shortest, not fastest, but fastest could also work. I am mostly looking for the shorter method, as this is a challenge that I put myself through, but this is one of the harder ones I believe. If i could vote, +1 for Correct Name

Comment: "Shortest" is rather a vague requirement. Do you mean "fewest lines of source code", "fewest bytes of source code", "fewest bytes of machine code", or something else? If you're using GCC, there are built-in functions like `__builtin_popcount()` that are not only short but will also use the built-in [`POPCNT` processor instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#POPCNT_and_LZCNT) where available.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage probably shortest test and debug time.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Shortest length of code.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage __builtin_popcount() seems to do what I want, post it as an answer?

Comment: Your code doesn't work for 0 btw.

Comment: Lol zero is the one thing I forgot @Ajay

Comment: @MartinJames do you mean the longest debug time :p

Comment: `r` should be initialized to zero. And integers are zero-initialized by default. So you can write `while(a&=a-1)r++;`

Comment: @AlejandroBlasco *integers are zero-initialized by default* ???? No local variable in C or C++ is initialized by default.

Comment: Code Golf is a game that was played on Stack Overflow in its early days, but it is now considered off-topic. Code Golf challenges should be posted in Programming Puzzles & Code Golf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution assumes `a` to have an unsigned type.

Yet the code does not work for `a = 0`. You can fix it this way:

```
r=!!a;while(a&=a-1)r++;
```

You can shave one character off this way:

```
for(r=!!a;a&=a-1;r++);
```

But here is an alternative solution with the same source length:

```
for(r=0;a;a/=2)r+=a&1;
```

As Lundin mentioned, code golfing is off topic on Stack Overflow.  It is a fun game, and one can definitely hone his C skills at trying to make the smallest code that is still fully defined for a given problem, but the resulting code is of poor value to casual readers trying to program at a more basic level.

Regarding the on topic part of your question, *The quickest method to compute the number of bits in an integer*: this problem has been studied intensively and several methods are available. Which one is fastest depends on many factors:

- how portable the code need to be. Some processors have built-in instructions for this and the compiler may provide a way to generate them via intrinsics or inline assembly.
- the expected range of values for the argument. If the range is small, a simple lookup table may yield the best performance.
- the distribution of values of the argument: if a specific value is almost always given, just testing for it might be the fastest solution.
- the cpu specific performance: different algorithms use different instructions, the relative performance of different cpus may differ.

Only careful benchmarking will tell you if a given approach is preferable to another, or if you are trying to optimise code whose performance is irrelevant. Provable correctness is **much** more important than micro-optimisation. Many experts consider optimisation to always be premature.

An interesting solution for 32-bit integers is this:

```
uint32_t bitcount_parallel(uint32_t v) {
    uint32_t c = v - ((v >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    c = ((c >> 2) & 0x33333333) + (c & 0x33333333);
    c = ((c >> 4) + c) & 0x0F0F0F0F;
    c = ((c >> 8) + c) & 0x00FF00FF;
    return ((c >> 16) + c) & 0x0000FFFF;
}
```

If multiplication is fast, here is a potentially faster solution:

```
uint32_t bitcount_hybrid(uint32_t v) {
    v = v - ((v >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    v = (v & 0x33333333) + ((v >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    return ((v + (v >> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24;
}
```

Different solutions are detailed here: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive

Comment: I have a value assigned for r before this, thus for(;a;a>>=1)r++; This was what I used before, so sorry, but nah,

Comment: I don't think the last one counts the number of ones, but the number of bits.

Comment: also use `a/=2` instead of `a>>=1` if we are in the business of saving source code bytes.

Comment: Your final solution can be fixed by using `r+=a|1` (or `r+=a%2`) instead of `r++`.

Comment: Questions regarding how to save source code symbols are off-topic on SO. If this was the question, we should close it and direct them to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @chqrlie this answers my question better than Lundin's. Currently designing a program/app that really needed this(on a windows friendly environment), and this actually did significantly boost the lag.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest possible code is to generate a look-up table, with the value of the variable as index. Example for uint8_t:

```
const uint8_t NUMBER_OF_ONES [256] =
{
  0, // 0
  1, // 1
  1, // 2
  2, // 3
  1, // 4
  2, // 5
  ...
  8, // 255
};
```

You would use it as `n = NUMBER_OF_ONES[a];`.

The second fastest is to generate smaller look-up tables, to save ROM. For example a nibble-wise look-up for numbers 0 to 15, which you would then call for every nibble in the data type.

Note that the requirement "Shortest as in shortest length of source code." is nonsense, that's not a metric used by professionals. If that's truly what you are after, for the sake of fun or obfuscation, then the question is off-topic on SO and should be asked at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: `8 * sizeof(uint8_t)` ? Do you mean `1 << (8 * sizeof(uint8_t))` for the size of the table?

Comment: This seems to be the fastest :) I will look for a method that will use this  and thanks alot @Lundin

Comment: @KyoungwanWoo: as a matter of fact, it is not even necessarily the fastest.